warning(gtk): configuration error: cli:1:/ invalid field ghostty
I successfully build ghostty terminal but when I try to open with ghosty with path then it showing me like this, here is more details.
verison
Ghostty 1.0.1-dev+0000000

Version
  - version: 1.0.1-dev+0000000
  - channel: tip
Build Config
  - Zig version: 0.13.0
  - build mode : builtin.OptimizeMode.ReleaseFast
  - app runtime: apprt.Runtime.gtk
  - font engine: font.main.Backend.fontconfig_freetype
  - renderer   : renderer.OpenGL
  - libxev     : main.Backend.io_uring
  - GTK version:
    build      : 4.8.3
    runtime    : 4.8.3
  - libadwaita : enabled
    build      : 1.2.2
    runtime    : 1.2.2
  - libX11     : enabled

ghostty ~/Downloads
info: ghostty version=1.0.1-dev+0000000
info: ghostty build optimize=ReleaseFast
info: runtime=apprt.Runtime.gtk
info: font_backend=font.main.Backend.fontconfig_freetype
info: dependency harfbuzz=8.4.0
info: dependency fontconfig=21402
info: renderer=renderer.OpenGL
info: libxev backend=main.Backend.io_uring
info(os): setlocale from env result=en_IN
info(gtk): GTK version build=4.8.3 runtime=4.8.3
info: reading configuration file path=/home/amar/.config/ghostty/config
info(config): default shell source=env value=/bin/bash
warning(gtk): configuration error: cli:1:/home/amar/Downloads: invalid field
warning(gtk): CLI errors detected, exiting

